# Jenkins library: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method xxx on null object

Tags: jenkins

I am using declarative pipelines and separate pipline helpers. In one of the helper I have the file `vars/getTriggerCause.groovy` with

```
/**
* Checks for cause of the job trigger and returns respective cause
* @return user, scm, time or other
*/
def String getCause() {
    echo "CAUSE ${currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().properties}"
    def cause = "${currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()}"
     if (cause =~ "UserIdCause") {
         return "user"
    }
}

/**
* Checks if trigger cause of the job is the timer
* @return true if trigger is timer
*/
def boolean isTime() {
    return this.call() == "time"
}
```

Now I want to use the function in the Jenkisfile like this

```
echo getTriggerCause().isTime()
```

Which results in an NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getCause() on null object
```

When I look at [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables) I would expect this works. The only difference to the linked example is that I load the library dynamically from scm.

Comment: Did you try removing the parentheses from `getTriggerCause`?
Like getTriggerCause.isTime()

Comment: @Vasiliki yes I figured out in meanwhile that the parentheses were  the problem. Do you mind to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the parentheses solve the problem so this works

```
getTriggerCause.isTime()
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error message when i was using load , problem was i had forgotten to return `this` from the groovy file.

Comment: I had exact the same case. Thanks